# how do I manually set a page number in a table of contents?

Tags: table-of-contents

I have a chapter (??) which is intended to be printed on the inside back cover of a booklet I am producing.  I want it listed in the table of contents, but with a pointer to 'insider back cover' in the ToC, not a page number.  Is this possible?  If so, how?

I have been trying code which looks like this:

```
\addtocontents{toc}{\contentsline{chapter}{\numberline{}{Mission of our organization}{inside back cover}}}
```

but keep getting compilation errors which read like so:

```
) [60] (./backmatter/01_mission.tex
! Argument of \contentsline has an extra }.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
l.4 ...our organization}{inside back cover}}}
                                                  
? q
```

Any guidance is appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: I just tried this:
`\setcounter{page}{inside back cover}`

but got this error message on compilation:
` [60] (./backmatter/01_mission.tex
! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
                   i
l.2 \setcounter{page}{inside back cover}`

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: If you are actually printing the last page, just use `\def\thepage{}` or possibly `\def\thepage{Cover}` anywhere on the last page.  `\pagestyle{empty}` might help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Two things:

1. You need to `\protect` content that you don't want expanded, since writing to the `.toc` will do that.
2. `\contentsline` takes *four* arguments.

[image]

```
\documentclass{book}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{A chapter}

\addtocontents{toc}{%
  \protect\contentsline{chapter}{\protect\numberline{}Mission of our organisation}{inside back cover}{}}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you Werner++.  That did the trick.  Its indented unlike the other entries, and is not linked to its content as are the other entries.  But it gives me an entry pointed to the inside back cover!  Thanks again!

Comment: So, what does `\protect` mean?  And how do I know when I need to use it?

Comment: @HughEsco: `\protect` avoids expansion and is often used when dealing with moving arguments (like `\caption`s, which print their contents to the LoF/LoT). See [What is the difference between Fragile and Robust commands? When and why do we need `\protect`?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/4736.5764)

Comment: By pointer are you talking hyperref?